# adding a vector already in span doesn't change span prove

Tags: vector-spaces

So I have to prove span($v_1, \dots , v_n)$ = span($v, v_1, \dots v_n)$ given that the v is in the span of span($v_1, \dots , v_n)$.

This seems trivial, but I seem to be getting stuck. I think I can show that if x is in the span of span($v, v_1, \dots v_n)$, then x is in the span of span($v_1, \dots , v_n)$. However, I am having a hard time $proving$ the other direction: adding something that is already in the span doesn't change the span.

Or if anyone could clarify Nicholas R. Peterson's answer that would be nice too.

Comment: Try to prove that $\langle v_1,\ldots,v_n\rangle\subseteq S \iff v_i\in S\;,\;i=1,2,\ldots,n$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Leverage the fact that $\DeclareMathOperator*{\span}{span}v\in\span(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$. Being in the span means that there are constants $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ such that
$$\tag{1}
v=a_1v_1+\cdots+a_nv_n.
$$
Now, clearly $\span(v_1,\ldots,v_n)\subseteq\span(v,v_1,\ldots,v_n)$; you need to show the reverse inclusion. So, suppose $w\in\span(v,v_1,\ldots,v_n)$, so that we can write
$$\tag{2}
w=b_0v+b_1v_1+\cdots+b_nv_n.
$$
Can you find a way to write this $w$ as a linear combination of $v_1,\ldots,v_n$, by leveraging what we know about $v$?

If so, then you have shown $w\in\span(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$.

Comment: I'm sure you can. but i don't know how.So no.

Comment: I'm sorry you feel that way; but, I can't give much more of a hint than that without giving away the whole thing.  Just try to think about how you can use equation (1) to rewrite equation (2).

Comment: there are totally different constants. can i just get rid of them? Now, I'm actually more confused by your answer.

Comment: I don't see how you can just take (2) and turn it into (1). all of the b's will have to become a's. and you can't simply insert (1) into (2) because that doesn't help.

Comment: What is the intuition here?  We have $w$ written as a linear combination of $v$ and $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ (see (2)). We want to write it as a linear combination of only $v_1,\ldots,v_n$. 

We know how to write $v$ as a linear combination of $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ (see (1)).  Could substituting this expression (1) for $v$ in to (2) further our goal?

Comment: no. hence my last comment. You just get a bigger expression full of a's, b's and v's.

Comment: Sure.  But what variable ISN'T involved in that new expression?

Comment: You don't have v. But how does that help us? we don't have w in terms of just a's and v_1 to v_n.

Comment: The $a$'s aren't part of the problem, and aren't the point.  Your goal is to find a sequence of scalars that show $w$ as a linear combination of $v_1,\ldots,v_n$. We've done that.

Comment: sorry, late night. got it.